# Can I get drunk by evaporating steam of alcohol?

Tags: boiling, alcohol

If I boil a bit alcohol in a pot, can I get drunk by inhaling the evaporating mixture?

Does the steam of alcohol still include any alcohol?

Comment: Google "vodka sauna".

Comment: dont forget this can kill you due to alcohol poisoning because you are unaware of how much you are taking in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yes, you can.](http://www.kmov.com/story/28458739/its-a-poison-trend-of-inhaling-alcohol-vapors-alarms-doctors) You can definitely become intoxicated, but this is not advised. When you drink alcohol, it is absorbed through the lining of your digestive system and passes through the bloodstream to reach your brain. This means that the alcohol will be buffered by the contents of your digestive system, getting you drunk more gradually. When inhaled, the alcohol is absorbed directly into the bloodstream through the lungs, so intoxication will happen much more quickly, not giving you time to "back off" if you think you've had too much.

Comment: The other thing to mention is that alcohol vapor is very inflammable and potentially explosive, and mixing it with flame is a bad idea, *especially* if you are intoxicated.

Comment: Funny...flammable...inflammable....ahh, the English language.

Comment: It's worse than that. Absorption starts in the nose. The alcohol gets to the brain without having to pass through the blood-brain barrier.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't think so. Absorbtion into mucous into blood. Nothing carries chemicals to the brain BUT blood. It doesn't have to get slowly absorbed through stomach, but it IS carried by blood.

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars Of course it is carried by blood, but by blood *above* the blood-brain barrier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can become intoxicated by inhaling the vapor from heated alcohol mixtures.

They have bars set up now that do this. They put a tea candle under a round glass full of whatever you want to get completely "fire in your veins" blistered drunk.

Images of the process [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQYdc.jpg)